# Injection CDI of Interface Returns NullPointerException

Tags: jax-rs, cdi

I have a problem with the injection in Java as I would like to inject an interface called RemoteStatisticService but it keeps returning null in this case thus error NullPointerException. I have tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399974/nullpointerexception-while-trying-to-access-inject-bean-in-constructor) with init() method and @PostConstruct but still gives me the same error.

Here is the code for MeasurementAspectService class:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import *.dto.MeasureDownloadDto;
import *.dto.MeasureUploadDto;
import *.rs.RemoteStatisticService;

public class MeasurementAspectService {

    private @Inject RemoteStatisticService remoteStatisticService;

    public void storeUploadDto(MeasureUploadDto measureUploadDto) {

        remoteStatisticService.postUploadStatistic(measureUploadDto);

    }

    public void storeDownloadDto(MeasureDownloadDto measureDownloadDto) {

        remoteStatisticService.postDownloadStatistic(measureDownloadDto);

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

    }

}
```

Here is the code for interface class RemoteStatisticService

```
import static *.util.RemoteServiceUtil.PRIV;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import *.dto.MeasureDownloadDto;
import *.dto.MeasureUploadDto;

@Path(PRIV + "stats")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public interface RemoteStatisticService {
    @POST
    @Path("upload")
    void postUploadStatistic(MeasureUploadDto mud);

    @POST
    @Path("download")
    void postDownloadStatistic(MeasureDownloadDto mdd);

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: To be valid for injection they need to marked as `@Named` beans for your CDI provider to handle, eg. `Weld`

Comment: where should I put @Named beans in this case? i'm using Maven and still new with CDI

Comment: At the class level eg. `@Named public class MeasurementAspectService`

Comment: What server/environment do you use? CDI 1.0 or CDI 1.1+?

Comment: @HaraldWellmann i think i'm using 1.1 in this case

Comment: @IhsanHaikal can you provide some sample code about how you get a reference to `MeasurementAspectService`?

Comment: @JohnAment [here](http://pastebin.com/TpWVXpBF) is the MeasurementAspect that calls MeasurementAspectService by instantiating it, it only excerpts as it is too long

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've defined an aspect using aspectj but are trying to get a reference to a CDI bean.  This isn't going to work.

This line here is the culprit:

`private final MeasurementAspectService measurementAspectService = new MeasurementAspectService();`

You'll need to use CDI to get a reference.  If you're using CDI 1.1, you can use this snippet.

`private final MeasurementAspectService measurementAspectService = CDI.current().select(MeasurementAspectService.class).get();`

This is because AspectJ isn't intended for CDI use.  Note that you can use [interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/learn/userguide/CDI-user-guide.html#interceptors) in CDI as well.

Comment: there is an error of CDI as it couldn't get reference to it. Do I need another package to be imported? I am using Maven and I believe i'm using Javax package imported from javax.validation group (artifact validation-api) of version 1.1.0.Final

Comment: ok I fixed the previous error, now the new error comes as "Exception while initializing MeasurementAspect: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate CDIProvider"

Comment: Are you sure that you're using CDI?

Comment: I'm not sure as well as I am using Maven and last I check I only use @Inject for this class

Comment: Well, what container are you deploying to? If tomcat, are you leveraging something like weld servlet for CDI?

Answer (score 0):

CDI 1.1+ works with implicit beans by default. You need to add a bean-defining annotation like `@Dependent` or `@ApplicationScoped` to any class you want to get picked up by CDI.